# Why can't I see my chosen language?

Tags: keyboard, indicator, gnome-shell, input-language

My chosen language is English (UK).

[image: screenshot]

It keeps turning down from time to time.

Comment: probably because there aren't any words on the screen... http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Comment: maybe it will help if you press super key and space. While super key is pressed you can alternate between installed languages pressing space several times.

Comment: Click the icon an reselect the (already selected) layout.